# Android Studio updates: patch cannot be applied

Tags: android-studio, patch, android-sdk-tools

each time when I'm doing (trying to do) update of SDK over Android Studio I get this error:

[image]

What to do? I had also updated Android Studio to 3.0, but this error occurs in previous version too.